# glassfish ldap authorization after spnego authentication

Tags: glassfish, ldap, java-ee-6, spnego, jaspic

We successfully implemented SSO with Apache mod_proxy_http and SPNEGO. In my Java EE 6 web application I get the authenticated user with request.getRemoteUser().

Now what would be the best way for authorization. Our goal is to check for a specific role membership of the user in our Microsoft AD over LDAP. What would be the best way to achieve that with glassfish 3.1.2?

Comment: Were you able to do that? If yes, would mind to add the answer here?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your usecase.
If you only want to know the roles from the AD you can do a manual search on the LDAP.

Example:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

public class test {

    public String ldapUri = "ldap://localhost";
    public String usersContainer = "cn=users,dc=example,dc=com"; // base DN for search
    public String username = "user";
    public String password = "pass";

    public static void main(String args[]){

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUri);
    env.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username );
    env.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password );
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

    try {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();

        String name = "your_username"; // full DN name
        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(usersContainer, "(member=" + name + ")",ctls );    

        while(answer.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult)answer.next();
                Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();
                System.out.println(attrs.get("cn"));
            }

        ctx.close();


    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    }
 }
```

Note that the username has to be the full DN of the user e.g.  `CN=user1,CN=users,DC=company,DC=com`

If you want to use these groups for role assignment in your application things are a bit tricky. To achieve that you'll probably need a custom [ServerAuthModule](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gizdx/index.html) (example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gizdx/index.html)) or you'll have to modify the SPNEGO part to assign roles based on data from the AD/LDAP.